# Clarification about the process of the Integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

I have found this formula of the integration by parts
$$\int uv dx = u \int v dx - \int u'\left(\int vdx\right) dx.$$
In the last term $\int u'\left(\int vdx\right) dx$, is it valid to put the inner integration outside assuming we have evaluated it?
$$\int uv dx = u \int v dx - \left(\int vdx\right)\int u' dx$$
A simple Fourier example,
$$u=x(t)e^{-j\omega t}$$$$ v=y(t)e^{-j\omega t}$$
$$\int uv dt = x(t)e^{-j\omega t} \int y(t)e^{-j\omega t} dt + j\omega \int x(t)e^{-j\omega t}\left(\int y(t)e^{-j\omega t} dt\right) dt.$$
$$=x(t)e^{-j\omega t} \mathcal{F}_y(\omega) + j\omega \int x(t)e^{-j\omega t}\Big(\mathcal{F}_y(\omega)\Big) dt.$$
$$=\mathcal{F}_y(\omega)\left[x(t)e^{-j\omega t}+j\omega \mathcal{F}_x(\omega)\right]$$

Comment: I would suggest that you try it with a simple example ...

Comment: Actually that presentation of IBP is a bit misleading. In $\int u'\big(\int vdx\big) dx$, the inner integral is “some antiderivative of $v$” and a function of the integration variable $x$ of the outer integral.

Comment: I have added an example on Fourier.

Comment: Based on wikipedia, this is the last term $\int \big(u'\int vdx\big) dx$ which I assume that I can integrate first the inner integral before multiplying with $u'$.

Comment: Yes. $V = \int v \, dx$ is some antiderivative of $v$, and then you have to compute $uV - \int u'V \, dx$.

Comment: I find $\int u(x)v'(x)\,dx=u(x)v(x)-\int u'(x)v(x)\,dx$ much easier to memorize, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Product_of_two_functions .

Comment: Since my $V$ is in terms of $\omega$, does it follow that I can put it outside the outer integration as what the example showed.

Comment: I have considered that version of i.b.p but I may not be able to simplify the equation based on $\mathcal{F}_y(\omega)$ as shown in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equation in
\begin{align}
\int uv dx &= u \int v dx - \int u'\left(\int vdx\right) dx\\
&=u \int v dx - \color{red}{\left(\int vdx\right)\int u' dx}
\end{align}
is wrong. I believe that the whole confusion comes from not using integration variables and integration limits.
Doing so we get
\begin{align}
\int_a^b u(x)v(x)\,dx &= \Big[u(x)\int_a^x v(y)\,dy\Big]_{x=a}^{x=b} -\underbrace{ \int_a^b u'(x)\left(\int_a^x v(y)\,dy\right) dx}_{(*)}\,.
\end{align}
The term $(*)$ we can write as
\begin{align}
&\int_a^b \int_a^x u'(x)v(y)\,dy\,dx\stackrel{\text{Fubini}}{=}
\int_a^b \int_y^b u'(x)v(y)\,dx\,dy\\
&=\int_a^b v(y)\int_y^b u'(x)\,dx\,dy=\int_a^b v(y)\Big(u(b)-u(y)\Big)\,dy\,.
\end{align}
Note that
$$
\Big[u(x)\int_a^x v(y)\,dy\Big]_{x=a}^{x=b}=u(b)\int_a^bv(y)\,dy
$$
so that we end up in total with
$$
\int_a^b u(x)v(x)\,dx = \int_a^b u(y)v(y)\,dy 
$$
as we should. In other words, when you use the notation $\int_a^x v(y)\,dy$ instead of $V(x)$ then integration by parts is nothing else than the Fubini theorem.